# Is there a way to do validation as part of a filter in Warp?

Tags: rust, rust-warp

I have a route and an endpoint function defined. I've also injected some dependencies.

```rust
pub fn route1() -> BoxedFilter<(String, ParamType)> {
    warp::get()
        .and(warp::path::param())
        .and(warp::filters::query::query())
        .and(warp::path::end())
        .boxed()
}

pub async fn handler1(
    query: String,
    param: ParamType,
    dependency: DependencyType,
) -> Result<impl warp::Reply, warp::Rejection> {
}
```

```rust
let api = api::routes::route1()
    .and(warp::any().map(move || dependency))
    .and_then(api::hanlders::hander1);
```

This all seems to work fine.

However, I want to be able to have something that sits in front of several endpoints that checks for a valid key in the query parameter. Inside `handler1` I can add:

```rust
if !param.key_valid {
    return Ok(warp::reply::with_status(
        warp::reply::json(&""),
        StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST,
    ));
}
```

I do not want to add this to every handler individually.

It seems like I should be able to do it via `filter`, but I can't figure it out.  I've tried using `.map()` but then returning multiple items shifts it to a tuple and I have to change my downstream function signature. Ideally I want to find a way to add verification or other filters that can reject the request without any downstream values knowing about them.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Is `param` needed inside of `handler1` once the validation has happened?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is effectively demonstrated by warp's [rejection example](https://github.com/seanmonstar/warp/blob/514af163f4f011c2d371cb207cfe3ccf43016abf/examples/rejections.rs):

> Rejections represent cases where a filter should not continue processing the request, but a different filter *could* process it.

> Extract a denominator from a "div-by" header, or reject with DivideByZero.

You need to

1. Use [`Filter::and_then`](https://docs.rs/warp/0.2.2/warp/trait.Filter.html#method.and_then) to take the existing filter (in this case `query()`) and perform the validation. If the validation fails, return a custom rejection.
2. Use [`Filter::recover`](https://docs.rs/warp/0.2.2/warp/trait.Filter.html#method.recover) to appropriately handle the custom rejection and any other possible errors.

Applied to your situation:

```
use serde::Deserialize;
use std::{convert::Infallible, net::IpAddr};
use warp::{filters::BoxedFilter, http::StatusCode, reject::Reject, Filter, Rejection, Reply};

fn route1() -> BoxedFilter<(String, ParamType)> {
    warp::get()
        .and(warp::path::param())
        .and(validated_query())
        .and(warp::path::end())
        .boxed()
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Invalid;
impl Reject for Invalid {}

fn validated_query() -> impl Filter<Extract = (ParamType,), Error = Rejection> + Copy {
    warp::filters::query::query().and_then(|param: ParamType| async move {
        if param.valid {
            Ok(param)
        } else {
            Err(warp::reject::custom(Invalid))
        }
    })
}

async fn report_invalid(r: Rejection) -> Result<impl Reply, Infallible> {
    let reply = warp::reply::reply();

    if let Some(Invalid) = r.find() {
        Ok(warp::reply::with_status(reply, StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST))
    } else {
        // Do better error handling here
        Ok(warp::reply::with_status(
            reply,
            StatusCode::INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
        ))
    }
}

async fn handler1(
    _query: String,
    _param: ParamType,
    _dependency: DependencyType,
) -> Result<impl warp::Reply, warp::Rejection> {
    Ok(warp::reply::reply())
}

struct DependencyType;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct ParamType {
    valid: bool,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let api = route1()
        .and(warp::any().map(move || DependencyType))
        .and_then(handler1)
        .recover(report_invalid);

    let ip: IpAddr = "127.0.0.1".parse().unwrap();
    let port = 8888;
    warp::serve(api).run((ip, port)).await;
}
```

And the output of curl with irrelevant lines removed:

```
% curl -v '127.0.0.1:8888/dummy/?valid=false'
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

% curl -v '127.0.0.1:8888/dummy/?valid=true'
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
warp = "0.2.2"
serde = { version = "1.0.104", features = ["derive"] }
tokio = { version = "0.2.13", features = ["full"] }
```

Comment: This is seems to be close enough to what I'm looking for.  Is there anyway to do it on the BoxedFilter instead, such that it would show up like `let api = route1().and(validated_query).and...` instead of it being during the route definition stage?