# How to properly handle errors from Warp route

Tags: rust, rust-warp

I'm trying to structure a non-trivial [warp](https://docs.rs/warp) REST application into modules while handling errors and rejections elegantly. It's not working out the way I expect. Consider this simple application:

main.rs

```
use warp_sample::routes;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    warp::serve(routes::convert_route()).run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 8080)).await;
}
```

routes.rs

```
use warp::{Filter, Rejection, Reply};
use crate::handlers;

pub fn convert_route() -> impl Filter<Extract = impl Reply, Error = Rejection> + Clone {
    warp::path("convert")
        .and(warp::path::param::<String>())
        .map(|v: String| {
            handlers::convert_str(&v).or_else(|e| e)
        })
}
```

handlers.rs

```
use warp::{Reply, Rejection};

pub fn convert_str(s: &str) -> Result<impl Reply, Rejection>{
    match s.parse::<i32>() {
        Ok(s) => Ok(warp::reply()),
        Err(_) => Err(warp::reject())
    }
}
```

This does not compile because in routes.rs I am trying to return a Rejection struct in the closure which does not match return type of `impl Reply`.

How do I get this to work? I have tried to change the return type of `convert_route` but that does not work with `warp::serve`.

For bonus marks, can you show me how to include a plain text respond in the handler when successful and a different status code when there is an error?

This does not work for the bonus, but it shows you what I am thinking.

```
pub fn convert_str(s: &str) -> Result<impl Reply, Rejection>{
    match s.parse::<i32>() {
        Ok(s) => Ok(warp::body(s)),
        Err(_) => Err(warp::Rejection {
            reason: Reason::BadRequest,
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: See also [How do I handle errors in Warp using both Rejection and the question-mark operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61013311/155423)

Answer (score 2):

You should only use [`map`](https://docs.rs/warp/0.3.1/warp/trait.Filter.html#method.map) when the operation you are doing is infallible. If you want to be able to return a rejection, you should use [`and_then`](https://docs.rs/warp/0.3.1/warp/trait.Filter.html#method.and_then) instead.
In your example, `convert_route` compiles correctly when changed to the code below.

```
pub fn convert_route() -> impl Filter<Extract = impl Reply, Error = Rejection> + Clone {
    warp::path("convert")
        .and(warp::path::param::<String>())
        .and_then(|v: String| async move { convert_str(&v) })
}
```

Of course in this example, `convert_str` is somewhat trivial and `convert_route` can be rewritten without it by simply changing the type in `.and(warp::path::param::<String>())`, but I assume the function is more involved in your real code.

For the bonus, you will want to create your own rejection type, which will allow you to handle it using [`recover`](https://docs.rs/warp/0.3.1/warp/trait.Filter.html#method.recover). Full code:

```
use warp::{hyper::StatusCode, reject::Reject, Filter, Rejection, Reply};

pub fn convert_route() -> impl Filter<Extract = impl Reply, Error = Rejection> + Clone {
    warp::path("convert")
        .and(warp::path::param::<String>())
        .and_then(|v: String| async move { convert_str(&v) })
        .recover(|err: Rejection| async move {
            if let Some(ConversionError) = err.find() {
                Ok(StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST)
            } else {
                Err(err)
            }
        })
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct ConversionError;
impl Reject for ConversionError {}

pub fn convert_str(s: &str) -> Result<impl Reply, Rejection> {
    match s.parse::<i32>() {
        Ok(s) => Ok(s.to_string()),
        Err(_) => Err(warp::reject::custom(ConversionError)),
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    warp::serve(convert_route())
        .run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 8080))
        .await;
}
```